# Update filed of an object atomically using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, atomic

We can use [SetValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue.aspx) method to set property of a method. But this operation isn't atomic. How can I update field of an object by reflection which will be atomic operation?

Comment: It really depends what you mean by "atomic", though I can't think of any (meaningful) definition where you could guarantee it using `SetValue()`: calling a property setter is actually just invoking an arbitrary method, over whose behavior you have no control.